# Snowflake: Is there a way to trigger to a stored procedure every time a specific table is appended?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Every time, I append a table with new data and then, run a procedure to move some of the new rows (subject to specific criteria). I'm looking to automate this process as much as possible.

I can't schedule a task, as the data I'm using to append the table arrives at different times of the day.

So, I was wondering if there's any way to call the aforementioned procedure every time the table is appended.

Comment: Snowflake doesn't support triggers - if that's the sort of thing you were looking for? What process are you running to load the new data into the table when it arrives and can you include the call to the SP as part of that process?

Comment: Hi , can you please give us the  table structure and sample  data, may be you can create a Materialized  view as in Snowflake,  Materialized views are automatically and maintained by Snowflake.